# I am trying to merge two arrays, one contains values and the other just contains the keys i would like to use for the array

Tags: php, arrays

I am querying LDAP for user's information, the information being pulled is the users role's.  some roles are assigned to a center and some are just global roles that are not center-specific

```
   $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr)or die('get info fail');
    foreach($info[$i]['memberof'] as $key => $value){
        $var = $info[$i]['memberof'][$key];
        $replaceSearch = array('dc=','dc=co','dc=uk','ou=Groups','ou=','cn=');
        $var = str_replace($replaceSearch,'',$var);
        $var = explode(',', $var);
        $var[$key] = array_filter($var);

        if(count($var[$key])!=1){
            $index = array('role','center','country','region');
        }else{
            $index = array('role');
        }
        $newArray[$key] = array_combine($index, $var[$key]);
    }
```

The error I get with this is with array_combine, it is saying that the two arrays are not the same size.  This is because some of the roles aren't specific to a center so the only items in these arrays are array = ('role' => 'WhateverRole') where as the roles that are specific to a center are array = ('role' => 'WhateverRole','center' => 'centerName','country' => 'countryName', 'region' => 'regionName').  This is why I say if(count($var[$key])!=1), setting $index based on the amount of elements in the array.  I'm not getting errors in php 5.4.16, but people with 5.3.xx are getting the array_combine error.  Is there an alternative I can use to prevent the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
            $ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
            $ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
            $result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
            print_r($result);
            ?> 
            The above example will output:

              Array
             (
               [color] => Array
                     (
                      [favorite] => Array
                      (
                          [0] => red
                          [1] => green
                       )

                      [0] => blue
                   )

              [0] => 5
              [1] => 10
            )

      You Can Merge Differennt Size of array Using  array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2) Method.
      learn More php.net
```

[image]